# Outlook 2013 with Scheduled View

Tags: c#, outlook-2013

A friend of mine tasked me with writing a simple program.  Open multiple calendars with a given view.  So I wrote a program to do just that using the Outlook Object Model to find the folders and listed the views.

However, it turns out that what she was after was a single view, the new "Schedule View" with the preselected calendar folders that she wanted to always be displayed, just in case someone unticked some or all but one of them.

I found the following link that shows how to activate the view, but nothing on how to select the given calendars.  What is worse is that Outlook doesn't allow you to record macro's so I can't see a way of finding out how to select the calendars wanted through code.

Does anyone have any ideas?

How to activate Scheduled View:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/90c01547-2b85-4d6d-8160-0ff33def6a88/schedule-view-not-available-in-olcalendarviewmode-enum?forum=vsto